# How to locate the element as per the given HTML

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```
<input value="Order (ESHOP)" class="btn" name="order_eshop" title="Order (ESHOP)" type="button" onclick="Sfdc.logServer('CUSTOM_URL_BUTTON', {id: '00b41000002iuj6', name: 'Order_ESHOP'}, Sfdc.Logging.LogLevel.INFO);
openIntegration('/servlet/servlet.Integration?scontrolCaching=1&amp;lid=00b41000002iuj6&amp;eid=a0863000007SV1q&amp;ic=1&amp;isdtp=vw&amp;linkToken=VmpFPSxNakF4T1MweE1TMHhNRlF5TVRvd09EbzBNaTQyT1RWYSx0eno3X1lSS1lOY1hORmtKb2ZvM3BxLFlXWmtNR0po', 'height=600,location=no,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=1', 1)">
```

I' am not able to find the *xpath* for this. I have same element on a single path **Order (ESHOP)**. When I'am trying to use indexing it is not finding the correct xpath.

Comment: <input value="Order (ESHOP)" class="btn" name="order_eshop" title="Order (ESHOP)" type="button" onclick="Sfdc.logServer('CUSTOM_URL_BUTTON', {id: '00b41000002iuj6', name: 'Order_ESHOP'}, Sfdc.Logging.LogLevel.INFO);
openIntegration('/servlet/servlet.Integration?scontrolCaching=1&amp;lid=00b41000002iuj6&amp;eid=a0863000007SV1q&amp;ic=1&amp;isdtp=vw&amp;linkToken=VmpFPSxNakF4T1MweE1TMHhNRlF5TVRvd09EbzBNaTQyT1RWYSx0eno3X1lSS1lOY1hORmtKb2ZvM3BxLFlXWmtNR0po', 'height=600,location=no,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=1', 1)">

Comment: I am here to learn things. Not helpful ^^

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: You need to spend some time cleaning up your question. Right now you are missing a lot of information. All relevant info needs to go into the question itself. Comments should be to answer questions, etc. but should not contain information that is necessary to answer the question. Add the HTML you posted into the comments and edit them into your question. You also need to add your current code and the result... error message, etc. and properly format them into the question.

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to locate/interact with the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.btn[name='order_eshop'][value='Order (ESHOP)'][title='Order (ESHOP)']")));
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='btn' and @name='order_eshop'][@value='Order (ESHOP)' and @title='Order (ESHOP)']")));
  ```